# How to deal if writev only write part of the data?

Tags: linux, sockets

My data is naturally segmented, and comes from different sources so I use the `writev` function as follows.

```c
char *buf0 = "short string\n";
struct bar *my_bar;
my_baz = get_my_baz();
iov[0].iov_base = buf0;
iov[0].iov_len = strlen(buf0);
iov[1].iov_base = my_bar;
iov[1].iov_len = sizeof (struct bar);
bytes_written = writev (sockfd, iov, 3);
```

I want to send all my data. What if writev only write partial data in one time, for example:

```c
bytes_written = 1;
```

How do I to continue to send the remain data?
In write function, we can [use this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014033/send-and-receive-a-file-in-socket-programming-in-linux-with-c-c-gcc-g?rq=1), how about writev?

Comment: Important note in the documentation: "The data transfers performed by `readv()` and `writev()` are atomic: **the data written by `writev()` is written as a single block** that is not intermingled with output from writes in other processes"  (Note: this guarantee is not part of POSIX, and OSes other than Linux might write only part of the data)

Comment: @BenVoight That doesn't preclude a short write in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @EJP: Of course it does, a short write or even automatically resumed operation wouldn't preserve atomicity.

Comment: @BenVoigt Your quotation talks about 'the data transfers performed'. I.e. what *actually* gets written. It doesn't state that all the data *presented by the user* gets written regardless of non-blocking mode, no space in the socket send buffer, etc. That would be a violation of non-blocking-mode semantics.

Comment: @EJP: Start with the basic definition of *atomic*.  It's perfectly possible to have non-blocking semantics for an atomic transfer, either the entire block fits in the buffer, or the call fails without writing anything, returning -1 and setting errno to EWOULDBLOCK.

Comment: @BenVoigt I can only repeat. It doesn't say that all the data presented is written. It says that the data that *is* written is written atomically.

Comment: @user207421: Atomic means exactly that the data is treated as one indivisible chunk, either all written or none of it is.  A partial write is not "atomic".  Atomic means that the operation cannot be split up into parts, so it's not possible for one part to succeed and one to fail, because **there are no parts**.

Comment: It is empirically possible for `writev` to do a short write. I made a test program that opened a non-blocking TCP stream to a remote server and wrote N iovecs. Each iovec was 1024B of the sequence "1234567890" repeated. `writev` did short writes of different lengths depending on the remote server - for `www.google.com:80` it was at 106350B, for `www.microsoft.com:80` at 1048576B, for `www.cloudflare.com:80` at 72800B. With microsoft and cloudflare a second writev failed because the remote server had hung up; with google it succeeded with an additional 107768B written. Kernel 5.10.16, x86_64

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Techniques for handling short reads/writes with scatter-gather?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853675/techniques-for-handling-short-reads-writes-with-scatter-gather)

Answer (score 6):

1. Increment `iov[0].iov_base` by `bytes_written`.
2. Decrement `iov[0].iov_len` by `bytes_written`.
3. Take care of underflows, i.e. if `iov[0].iov_len` goes negative, remember it, set it to zero, and propagate the difference into `iov[1]` in the same way as (1) and (2), and so on until closure.

However if you're in blocking mode this is a non-issue, as the case of a short write can never arise.

Comment: You answer means that in writev function the data is written one by one in the order of iov[0] to iov[n]?

Comment: @zwfars That's what the documentation says. Surely you've read it?

Comment: but iov in writev is const: ssize_t writev(int __fd, const struct iovec* __iov, int __count); , you can't modify iov_base and iov_len.

Comment: @Ted The `const` means that `writev()` can't modify it, not that you can't.

Comment: Short writes *can* arise in blocking mode.

Comment: @ZachB Only if a signal occurs, and if you're not ignoring `SIG_INT` I have no help for you.